# AWS EventBridge DynamoDB detail event pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

This is the format of my JSON events, incoming from another AWS account EventBridge into my own AWS account EventBridge bus.

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "e53c5be7-0ea4-4590-1ed5-4c4db642401c",
    "detail-type": "Event from aws:dynamodb",
    "source": "Pipe dynamodb-pipe-my-service-dev",
    "account": "000000000000",
    "time": "2023-08-17T12:51:39Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "eventID": "eea64ea701c786e930845b8397e34c57",
        "eventName": "MODIFY",
        "eventVersion": "1.1",
        "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "dynamodb": {
            "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1692276699,
            "Keys": {
                "SK": {
                    "S": "TYPE#CONFIG"
                },
                "PK": {
                    "S": "PROJECT#2HuNAorgCkkyAL6vIEUduu8G2Ya"
                }
            },
            "NewImage": {...}
...
```

The changing part is SK and PK.

Sometimes [ SK = TYPE#PLAN, PK = "SERVICE#123" ].
Sometimes [ SK = TYPE#CONFIG, PK = "PROJECT#321" ].

I want only the latter to be forwarded to my target.

My `aws_cloudwatch_event_rule` features:

```
event_pattern = jsonencode({
    "detail" : {
      "dynamodb" : {
        "Keys" : {
          "PK" : {
            "S" : {
              "prefix" : ["PROJECT#"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Unfortunately, no events reach my target.

While, with a wildcard filter like `{"source" : [{"prefix" : ""}]` both event types (all, in fact) are forwarded.

Can you please help me fix my event_pattern in order to get only PK starting w/ `PROJECT#`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the `detail` aspect which is not relevant on a DynamoDB event, you should be able to access the params like this:

```
{"dynamodb": {"NewImage": {"PK": {"S": [{"prefix": "PROJECT"}]}}}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the pattern filter from the root of the object. Please check my sample event in the question above. I tried your patter as-is and doesn't let events go through. Where is your idea of dropping the top level json prop "detail" documented, btw?

Answer (score -2):

Your [`prefix`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html#eb-filtering-prefix-matching) syntax is incorrect, try:

```
"S" : [ { "prefix" : "PROJECT#" } ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately. That doesn't work either: `{"detail":{"dynamodb":{"Keys":{"PK":{"S":[{"prefix":"PROJECT#"}]}}}}}`